# How to bind data from two different nested objects to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I curretly have a View which is supposed to show data from two different Objects. Tod do so i created a view model which contains a list of an object type that contains the two different objects mentioned before. The two objects are Suppliers and Items.
Items class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


namespace MLaRealERP.Models
{
    public class Insumo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("proveedorId")]
        public int ProveedorId { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("tipo")]
        public string Tipo { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("unidad")]
        public string Unidad { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("precio")]
        public float Precio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Suppliers Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


namespace MLaRealERP.Models
{
    public class Proveedor
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("celular")]
        public string Celular { get; set; }

        public void NuevoProveedor(string n, string c)
        {
            Name = n;
            Celular = c;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MLaRealERP.Models;

namespace MLaRealERP.ViewModels
{
    public class InsumosViewModel
    {
        public class InsumoVM
        {
            public Insumo insumo { get; set; }
            public Proveedor proveedor { get; set; }

        }
        List<Insumo> repo;
        List<Proveedor> proveedores;
        public List<InsumoVM> insumos;
        //IOrderedEnumerable<Proveedor> proveedores;
        public InsumosViewModel()
        {
            repo = new List<Insumo>();
            proveedores = new List<Proveedor>();
            insumos = new List<InsumoVM>();
        }
        public async void InitializeViewModel()
        {
            repo = await Funciones.GetAll<Insumo>("insumos", App.client);
            proveedores = await Funciones.GetAll<Proveedor>("proveedors", App.client);
            proveedores = proveedores.OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
            

            //proveedores = repo.OrderBy(repo => repo.Id);
            foreach(Insumo insumo in repo)
            {
                newInsumoVM(insumo);
            }
        }
        private void newInsumoVM(Insumo ins)
        {
            InsumoVM insumoVM = new InsumoVM();
            insumoVM.insumo = ins;
            insumoVM.proveedor = proveedores[ins.ProveedorId - 1];
            insumos.Add(insumoVM);
        }

    }
}
```

Data Grid Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MLaRealERP.Views.InsumosView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MLaRealERP.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="InsumosView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <TextBox  Canvas.Left="10"  Name="txtFilter" TextChanged="txtFilter_TextChanged" Width="171" />
            <Button  Canvas.Right="10" Name="btnAddInsumo" Click="btnAddInsumo_Click">Agregar Nuevo Producto</Button>
        </Canvas>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding insumos}" Name="dgInsumos" Margin="10" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding insumos.insumo.Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding insumos.insumo.Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo" Binding="{Binding insumos.insumo.Tipo}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Datagrid cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MLaRealERP.ViewModels;

namespace MLaRealERP.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for InsumosView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class InsumosView : Window
    {
        InsumosViewModel insumos;
        public InsumosView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            insumos = new InsumosViewModel();
            insumos.InitializeViewModel();
            dgInsumos.DataContext = insumos;
        }

        //public async void LoadViewItems()
        //{
        //    insumos.InitializeViewModel();
        //}
        private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddInsumo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to show Isumos `id`, `name`, and `tipo` along with proveedores `name`.

EDIT:
Current View.xaml for the grid

```
<Window x:Class="MLaRealERP.Views.InsumosView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MLaRealERP.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="InsumosView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <TextBox  Canvas.Left="10"  Name="txtFilter" TextChanged="txtFilter_TextChanged" Width="171" />
            <Button  Canvas.Right="10" Name="btnAddInsumo" Click="btnAddInsumo_Click">Agregar Nuevo Producto</Button>
        </Canvas>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding insumos}" DataContext="{Binding InsumoVM}" Name="dgInsumos" Margin="10" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding insumo.Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding insumo.Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo" Binding="{Binding insumo.Tipo}" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Never define a `async void` method (except the method is an event handler). An `async` method must always return a `Task` or `Task<T>`: `async Task InitializeViewModel() { ... }`

Comment: Also when using MVVM you should not pass data directly to the view. For example, instead of passing a `List<Cliente>` to the `ClientesView`, let the `ClientesView` bind its controls like `dgClients` to a property on the DataContext/view model class. `List<Cliente>` must be a property of the view model class.

Comment: To filter data for ItemsControl like a DataGrid use the collection view: `dgClientes.Items.Filter = item => (items as Cliente).Apellidos.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower());` Don't create a new collection that you assign to the `ItemsSource` for this purpose. It will become difficult to maintain very quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issue with your code:

1. **Required Fix**: You can only bind to public properties and not fields. This means `insumos` must be a public property. Additionally the binding source, in this case the `InsumosViewModel` and the `InsumoVM` classes, must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (see Microsoft Docs for complete [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-6.0#examples)) - even when you don't expect property changes.

**InsumoVM.cs**

```
public class InsumoVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Insumo Insumo { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
}
```

**InsumosViewModel.cs**

```
public class InsumosViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<InsumoVM> Insumos { get; }
    private List<Insumo> Repo { get; set; }
    private List<Proveedor> Proveedores { get; set; }

    public InsumosViewModel()
    {
        this.Repo = new List<Insumo>();
        this.Proveedores = new List<Proveedor>();
        this.Insumos = new ObservableCollection<InsumoVM>();
    }

    public async Task InitializeViewModel()
    {
        this.Repo = await Funciones.GetAll<Insumo>("insumos", App.client);
        this.Proveedores = (await Funciones.GetAll<Proveedor>("proveedors", App.client)).
          OrderBy(p => p.Id)
          .ToList();
        
        this.Insumos.Clear();
        foreach(Insumo insumo in this.Repo)
        {
            NewInsumoVM(insumo);
        }
    }

    private void NewInsumoVM(Insumo ins)
    {
        InsumoVM insumoVM = new InsumoVM()
        {
          Insumo = ins,
          Proveedor = proveedores[ins.ProveedorId - 1]
        };
        this.Insumos.Add(insumoVM);
    }
}
```

2. **Required Fix**: You must use the correct `Binding.Path`. The items are of type `InsumoVM`. Therefore `InsumoVM` is the type of the `DataContext` of each column:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Insumos}">
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Insumo Name" 
                      Binding="{Binding Insumo.Name}" />
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Proveedor Name" 
                      Binding="{Binding Proveedor.Name}" />
</DataGrid>
```

3. Never return `void` from an `async` method (except this method is an event handler). A `async` method must return `Task` or `Task<T>`:

```cs
public async Task InitializeViewModel()
{}
```

4. Also when using MVVM you should not pass data directly to the view. For example, instead of passing a `List<Cliente>` to the `ClientesView`, let the `ClientesView` bind its controls like `dgClients` to a property on the `DataContext`/view model class. `List<Cliente>` must be a property of the view model class.
5. To filter data for `ItemsControl` like a `DataGrid` use the collection view. Don't create a new collection that you assign to the ItemsSource for this purpose. It will become difficult to maintain very quick.

```cs
dgClientes.Items.Filter = item => (items as Cliente).Apellidos.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer and your comments, i already tried using the binding provided but the data isn't showing, i Only get the empty columns, no lines, just the headers

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Please implement fixes 1) and 2) to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to wpf and mvvm. Do you recommend any source for further knowledge/reference. I'm working on an ERP.

Comment: Just read the Microsoft documentation, for example [Data Templating Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) or [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0). You will get some important insights from the documentation alone. If you follow the links to related content you can get quite deep. You can also start from the API documentation. The remarks section also contains useful information. It really depends on the kind of information you seek.